# Using this in promise callback

Tags: javascript, promise, angularfire2

I have the following code:

```
private resetPassword() {

    this.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        this.firebaseRef.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(auth.auth.email).then(
            success => {
                this.successMessage = 'A password reset email was sent to ' + auth.auth.email + '. Please follow' +
                    'the instructions in the email to reset your password.';
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    });

}
```

The issue that I'm having is that `this.successMessage` is not set on success.  I can put a `console.log` there and it works, but it seems that I'm not able to reference `this` in that scope.  I've tried using `.bind(this)` wherever I could, but it didn't help.  Any thoughts?

Note that this is an Angular2 app, and `successMessage` is being rendered in the template, so that's how I know it is not working.  I have confirmed that if I set the message outside of `then` that it works properly.

Comment: "The issue that I'm having is that this.successMessage is not set on success" — How can you tell? Your code never tries to read the value back. You need to make sure your [mcve] is *complete*.

Comment: This is an Angular2 app that displays `successMessage` in the template, and that is not happening.  And yes, I made sure that if I set the message outside of `then` that it works properly.  I will update my original post with this info.

Comment: @EvanSalter could just be that your angular app is failing to update after an async action rather than the value not being set? Does doing a `console.log(this)` print `undefined` or does it show that successMessage has been actually set?

Comment: @AR7 gave it a shot and I did get an object back, plus `successMessage` is set properly when `this` is logged out, so I think you may be right.  I'll look into that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AR7, I figured out the solution.  `this.successMessage` was updating properly, but the Angular2 template wasn't updating.  I resolved this by wrapping the `this.successMessage` assignment in an `ngZone.run`:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
...
private resetPassword() {

    this.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        this.firebaseRef.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(auth.auth.email).then(
            success => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    this.successMessage = 'A password reset email was sent to ' + auth.auth.email + '. Please follow' +
                        'the instructions in the email to reset your password.';
                });
                console.log(this);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    });

}
```